# resetting cumsum if value goes to negative in r

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, cumsum

```
ve <- c(17, -9, 9, -17, 17, -17, 11, -9, 16, -18, 17, 0, 0, -18, 17, 0, 0, -17, 14, -14, 17, -2, 0, -15, 9, -9, 17, -16, 16, -17, 17, -17, 17, -17, 17, -17, 17, -8, 7, -16, 17, -14, 14, -10, 10, -16, 16, -10, 10, -12, 12, -11, 11, -17, 17, -17, 17, -9, 8, -17, 17, -17, 17, -16, 16, -17, 17, -8, 8, -9, 9, -17, 17, -17, 17, -13, 13, -10, 7, -10, 13, -16, 17, -13, 13, -13, 13, -9, 8, -17, 17, -10, 9, -17, 17, -17, 17, -16, 16, -10, 10, -15, 15, -14, 14, -14, 15, -13, 13, -9, 9, -13, 13, -12, 12, -10, 9, -11, 12, -8, 7, -10, 10, -9, 9, -11, 11, -9, 9, -7, 7, -12, 11, -11, 12, -11, 11, -14, 14, -13, 13, -10, 10, -13, 13, -17, 17, -7, 7, -17, 17, -17, 17, -14, 14, NA)

df <- data.frame(ve = ve, calc = 0)
```

I need to calculate cumsum in column calc, but it needs to reset to zero and start again whenever its value goes negative..
I've tried several conditions but it's not really working...

Also, is it possible to achieve this in dplyr? I'm new to dplyr and find it somewhat difficult whenever I need to use dependent value..

Thank you for your help!

it should go as..

```
     ve calc
1    17    17
2    -9    8
3     9    17
4   -17    0
5    17    17
6   -17    0
7    11    11
8    -9    2
9    16    18
10  -18    0
11   17    17
12    0    17
13    0    17
14  -18    0
15   17    17
```

If you see row 14 and 15, with the normal cumsum it would be -1 and 16
but I want it to reset to 0 instead of -1 and continue cumsum, hence the next would be 17

Comment: do you want to omit `NAs`?

Comment: oh yes, NA needs to be omitted please

Comment: Can you provide example output? I'm not sure exactly how the cumsum works when it hits a negative (e.g. starting from 0 at the next positive value, including the negative in the cumsum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `replace` the NA values with 0 and use `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
      group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(cumsum(replace(ve, is.na(ve), 0)) < 0, default = TRUE))) %>%
     mutate(calc = cumsum(replace(ve, is.na(ve), 0)), calc = replace(calc, calc < 0, 0)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(-grp)
head(df1, 15)
# A tibble: 15 x 2
#      ve  calc
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    17    17
# 2    -9     8
# 3     9    17
# 4   -17     0
# 5    17    17
# 6   -17     0
# 7    11    11
# 8    -9     2
# 9    16    18
#10   -18     0
#11    17    17
#12     0    17
#13     0    17
#14   -18     0
#15    17    17
```

Answer (score 2):

base R's `Reduce` or `purrr::accumulate` are designed for these scenarios

```r
df$calc <- Reduce(\(.x, .y) ifelse(.x + .y < 0, 0, .x + .y), df$ve, accumulate = TRUE)
df
#>      ve calc
#> 1    17   17
#> 2    -9    8
#> 3     9   17
#> 4   -17    0
#> 5    17   17
#> 6   -17    0
#> 7    11   11
#> 8    -9    2
#> 9    16   18
#> 10  -18    0
#> 11   17   17
#> 12    0   17
#> 13    0   17
#> 14  -18    0
#> 15   17   17
.
.
.
```

---

or in `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(calc = accumulate(ve,  ~ ifelse(.x + .y < 0, 0, .x + .y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using `dplyr`, but this should work:

```
ve = as.data.frame(ve)
ve = na.omit(ve)
ve$cumS = 0
ve$cumS[1] = ve$ve[1]

for (i in 2 : length(ve$ve)) {

ve$cumS[i] = ifelse((ve$cumS[i - 1] + ve$ve[i]) < 0,
                     0, (ve$cumS[i - 1] + ve$ve[i]))
}
```

Comment: This looks about right, but I think it fails because your `ifelse` statement doesn't actually do anything, you would need to assign the result to `ve$cumS[i]` I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an iterative solution. I can't think of how to do this vectorized/using `dplyr` without multiple passes over the data, but I'm sure someone else will:

```
ve_csum = numeric(length(ve))

current_total = 0
for (i in 1:length(ve)) {
    if (is.na(ve[i])) {
        ve_csum[i] = current_total
        next
    }
    current_total = current_total + ve[i]
    if (current_total < 0) {
        current_total = 0
    }
    ve_csum[i] = current_total
}

result = data.frame(ve, ve_csum)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
> df$calc=ifelse(cumsum(df$ve)<0,0,cumsum(df$ve))
```