# dplyr / R cumulative sum with reset

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to generate cumulative sums with a reset if the "current" sum exceeds some threshold, using dplyr. In the below, I want to cumsum over 'a'.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

tib <- tibble(
  t = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  a = c(2,3,1,2,2,3)
)

# what I want
## thresh = 5
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#         t     a     g     c
#      <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#   1  1.00  2.00     0  2.00
#   2  2.00  3.00     0  5.00
#   3  3.00  1.00     1  1.00
#   4  4.00  2.00     1  3.00
#   5  5.00  2.00     1  5.00
#   6  6.00  3.00     2  3.00

# what I want
## thresh = 4
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#         t     a     g     c
#      <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#   1  1.00  2.00     0  2.00
#   2  2.00  3.00     0  5.00
#   3  3.00  1.00     1  1.00
#   4  4.00  2.00     1  3.00
#   5  5.00  2.00     1  5.00
#   6  6.00  3.00     2  3.00

# what I want
## thresh = 6
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#         t     a     g     c
#      <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#   1  1.00  2.00     0  2.00
#   2  2.00  3.00     0  5.00
#   3  3.00  1.00     0  6.00
#   4  4.00  2.00     1  2.00
#   5  5.00  2.00     1  4.00
#   6  6.00  3.00     1  7.00
```

I've examined many of the similar questions here (such as [resetting cumsum if value goes to negative in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512075/resetting-cumsum-if-value-goes-to-negative-in-r)) and have gotten what I hoped was close, but no.

I've tried variants of

```
thresh <-5
tib %>%
  group_by(g = cumsum(lag(cumsum(a) >= thresh, default = FALSE))) %>%
  mutate(c = cumsum(a)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
      t     a     g     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1  1.00  2.00     0  2.00
2  2.00  3.00     0  5.00
3  3.00  1.00     1  1.00
4  4.00  2.00     2  2.00
5  5.00  2.00     3  2.00
6  6.00  3.00     4  3.00
```

You can see that the "group" is not getting reset after the first time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you can use `accumulate()` here to help. And i've also made a wrapper function to use for different thresholds

```
sum_reset_at <- function(thresh) {
  function(x) {
    accumulate(x, ~if_else(.x>=thresh, .y, .x+.y))
  }  
}

tib %>% mutate(c = sum_reset_at(5)(a))
#       t     a     c
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     2     2
# 2     2     3     5
# 3     3     1     1
# 4     4     2     3
# 5     5     2     5
# 6     6     3     3
tib %>% mutate(c = sum_reset_at(4)(a))
#       t     a     c
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     2     2
# 2     2     3     5
# 3     3     1     1
# 4     4     2     3
# 5     5     2     5
# 6     6     3     3
tib %>% mutate(c = sum_reset_at(6)(a))
#       t     a     c
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     2     2
# 2     2     3     5
# 3     3     1     6
# 4     4     2     2
# 5     5     2     4
# 6     6     3     7
```

Comment: This is looking brilliant. Thanks. Now what if I want to reset based on either the threshold OR the delta between the "current" t and the last t since reset exceeding another threshold? Either condition triggers reset (That's a new question, should I open a new stackoverflow?)

Comment: Hi MrFlick, I don't understand how you're passing the column to the function.. I see that it takes the form of sum_reset_at(thresh)(columname) but I don't understand how function(x)(y) works? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @variable sum_reset_at is a function that returns a function. So the first () builds a functions with a certain threshold and the second () calls that function on a vector of data.

Answer (score 1):

if you're interested in the group building based on `cumsum < threshold`

You can use the following `base::` function:

```
cumSumReset <- function(x, thresh = 4) {
    ans    <- numeric()
    i      <- 0

    while(length(x) > 0) {
        cs_over <- cumsum(x)
        ntimes <- sum( cs_over <= thresh )
        x      <- x[-(1:ntimes)]
        ans <- c(ans, rep(i, ntimes))
        i   <- i + 1
    }
    return(ans)
}
```

call:

```
tib %>% mutate(g = cumSumReset(a, 5))
```

result:

```
#   A tibble: 6 x 3
#      t     a     g
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     0
#2     2     3     0
#3     3     1     1
#4     4     2     1
#5     5     2     1
#6     6     3     2
```

---

- with the group `g` you can now do whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit old question, but I came across this while searching for a similar question and thus thought to include this alternate approach here too.

library `MESS` has a inbuilt function `cumsumbinning()` for these kind of requirements.  Since here you need to cross that `threshold` before stopping, you can use it like this (using `threshold - 1` and setting `cutwhenpassed = TRUE` in the third argument.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(MESS)

tib <- tibble(
  t = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  a = c(2,3,1,2,2,3)
)
n <- 5 # threshold

tib %>%
  group_by(g = cumsumbinning(a, n-1, TRUE) -1) %>%
  mutate(c = cumsum(a))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   g [3]
#>       t     a     g     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     0     2
#> 2     2     3     0     5
#> 3     3     1     1     1
#> 4     4     2     1     3
#> 5     5     2     1     5
#> 6     6     3     2     3

n <- 4 # threshold

tib %>%
  group_by(g = cumsumbinning(a, n-1, TRUE) -1) %>%
  mutate(c = cumsum(a))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   g [3]
#>       t     a     g     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     0     2
#> 2     2     3     0     5
#> 3     3     1     1     1
#> 4     4     2     1     3
#> 5     5     2     1     5
#> 6     6     3     2     3

n <- 6 # threshold

tib %>%
  group_by(g = cumsumbinning(a, n-1, TRUE) -1) %>%
  mutate(c = cumsum(a))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   g [2]
#>       t     a     g     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     0     2
#> 2     2     3     0     5
#> 3     3     1     0     6
#> 4     4     2     1     2
#> 5     5     2     1     4
#> 6     6     3     1     7
```