# make a variable based on a cumulative sum with reset based on condition

Tags: r

I want a variable such as `desired_output`, based on a cumulative sum over `cumsumover`, where the `cumsum` function resets every time it reaches the next number in `thresh`.

```
cumsumover <- c(1, 2, 7, 4, 2, 5)
thresh <- c(3, 7, 11)
desired_output <- c(3, 3 ,7 ,11 ,11 ,11) # same length as cumsumover
```

This question is similar, but I can't wrap my head around the code. 
[dplyr / R cumulative sum with reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076769/dplyr-r-cumulative-sum-with-reset)

Compared to similar questions my condition is specified in a vector of different length than the `cumsumover`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Bonus if both a base R and a tidyverse approach is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can use `cut` with `breaks` as `thresh` and `labels` as `letters` of same length as `thresh`.

```
cut(cumsum(cumsumover),breaks = c(0, thresh[-1], max(cumsum(cumsumover))),
          labels = letters[seq_along(thresh)])

#[1] a a b c c c
```

Replaced the last element of `thresh` with `max(cumsum(cumsumover))` so that anything outside last element of `thresh` is assigned the last `label`.

---

If we want `labels` as `thresh` instead of `letters`

```
cut(cumsum(cumsumover),breaks = c(0, thresh[-1], max(cumsum(cumsumover))),labels = thresh)
#[1] 3  3  7  11 11 11
```

Comment: I added a more general example, because I got the error: `'breaks' are not unique`

Comment: @dzgreen it is not advisable to continuously change your question. Each question should be solving only one unique problem.  I would suggest you to ask a new question.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

data:

```
cumsumover <- c(1, 2, 7, 4, 2, 5)
thresh     <- c(3, 7, 11)
```

code:

```
outp <- letters[1:3] # to make solution more general
cumsumover_copy <- cumsumover  # I use <<- inside sapply so therefore I make a copy to stay save

unlist(
sapply(seq_along(thresh), function(x) {
    cs_over <- cumsum(cumsumover_copy)
    ntimes = sum( cs_over <= thresh[x] )
    cumsumover_copy <<- cumsumover_copy[-(1:ntimes)]
    return( rep(outp[x], ntimes) )
                             } )
)
```

result:

```
#[1] "a" "a" "b" "c" "c" "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.bincode` you can do this:

```
thresh[.bincode(cumsum(cumsumover), c(-Inf,thresh[-1],Inf))]
[1]  3  3  7 11 11 11
```

`.bincode` is used by `cut`, which basically adds labels and checks, so it's more efficient:

```
 x <-rep(cumsum(cumsumover),10000)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  bincode   = thresh[.bincode(x, c(-Inf,thresh[-1],Inf))],
  cut       = cut(x,breaks = c(-Inf, thresh[-1], Inf),labels = thresh))
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#  bincode  450.2  459.75  654.794  482.10  642.20  5028.4   100
#      cut 1739.3 1864.90 2622.593 2215.15 2713.25 12194.8   100
```