# Create a sequence of numbers that increments for every change in another variable

Tags: r

What is an efficient way to create a sequence of numbers that increments for each change in a group variable? As a toy example, using the data frame below, I would like a new variable, "Value", to take on the values `c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4)`. Note that even though 48 repeats itself, "Value" still increases as I'm only concerned with a change in the sequence.

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
  'Group 
  48 
  48
  48
  56
  56
  48
  48
  14'), header = TRUE)
```

One way to do this is

```
df$Value<-1
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
if(df[i,]$Group==df[i-1,]$Group){df[i,]$Value=df[i-1,]$Value}
else{df[i,]$Value=df[i-1,]$Value+1}
}
```

but this is very slow. My actual dataset has several million observations.

**Note:** I had a difficult time wording the title of this question so please change it if you'd like.

Comment: This is `data.table::rleid(df$Group)`

Comment: The tidyverse team [credit inspiration from](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/02/dplyr-1-1-0-vctrs/#consecutive_id) `data.table::rleid()` for their equivalent, `dplyr::consecutive_id()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We also could hack the `rle`.

```
r <- rle(df$Group)
r$values <- seq_along(r$lengths)
inverse.rle(r)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4
```

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(48L, 48L, 48L, 56L, 56L, 48L, 48L, 14L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44512144/3772141

Just do this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Value = cumsum(Group != lag(Group) | row_number() == 1))
```

Result:

```
# Group Value
#    48     1
#    48     1
#    48     1
#    56     2
#    56     2
#    48     3
#    48     3
#    14     4
```

How it works:

1. compare `Value` with `Value` from the previous row. If it changes set it to `TRUE`, indicating here begins an new Value: `Group != lag(Group)`
2. The first element the lag function returns is `NA`. But it should always to be `TRUE` for the first row: `| row_number() == 1`
3. `TRUE` and `FALSE` can be represented as `1` and `0`. So with the `cumsum` function `Value` gets incremented whenever the inner expression returns `TRUE` which is when `Group` changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the tidyverse, `dplyr 1.1.0` has the function `consecutive_id()` which does exactly what you want! The tidyverse team recommend it for use on Zoom call transcripts, where consecutive lines attributed to the same speaker should be grouped together as a single idea: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/02/dplyr-1-1-0-vctrs/#consecutive_id

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(textConnection(
  'Group 
  48 
  48
  48
  56
  56
  48
  48
  14'), header = TRUE)

df |> mutate(value = consecutive_id(Group))
#>   Group value
#> 1    48     1
#> 2    48     1
#> 3    48     1
#> 4    56     2
#> 5    56     2
#> 6    48     3
#> 7    48     3
#> 8    14     4
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(Group = c(48, 
                      48,
                      48,
                      56,
                      56,
                      48,
                      48,
                      14))

# Get unique values in group
unique_vals = unique(df$Group)

# create a sequence from 1 up until the length of the unique values vector
sequential_nums = 1:length(unique_vals)

# Create a new column looking up the current value in the unique_vals list
# and replacing it with the correct sequential number
df %>% 
  mutate(Value = sequential_nums[match(Group, unique_vals)])

# Group      Value 
# 1    48         1
# 2    48         1
# 3    48         1
# 4    56         2
# 5    56         2
# 6    48         1
# 7    48         1
# 8    14         3
```